# Doctrine 2 - strange findBy() function

Tags: php, database, doctrine-orm

i tried to fetch data from database with Doctrine 2, but I have problem with findBy() function.

I have entity **User**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\id
 * @ORM\generatedValue
 * @ORM\column(type="integer")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\column(type="string", length=32, unique=true)
 */
private $user;
```

And entity **UserList**:

```
/**
 * @ORM\id
 * @ORM\generatedValue(strategy="NONE")
 * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\oneToOne(targetEntity="User")
 * @ORM\joinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $parent = null;
```

I have table with data:

```
Users:
 +----+------+
 | id | user |
 +----|------+
 | 1  | John |
 | 2  | Jane |
 | 3  | Doe  |
 +----+------+

UsersList (id 3 have two parents):
 +---------+-----------+
 | user_id | parent_id |
 +---------|-----------+
 |    1    |    NULL   |
 |    2    |    NULL   |
 |    3    |     1     |
 |    3    |     2     |
 +---------+-----------+
```

I want to get Doe's (id 3) parents:

```
 $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository('User')->findByUser('Doe');
 $user_parents = $this->entityManager->getRepository('UserList')->findById($user);

 foreach($user_parents as $parent)
 {
     var_dump($parent);
 }
```

Return:

```
 UserList(2) {
    id private => 3
    parent private => 1
 }
 UserList(2) {
    id private => 3
    parent private => 1 //this should be 2
 }
```

Where is the problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `@Id` annotation to your `UserList::$parent` property.

Comment: No. I want to fetch all records with id 3. Problem is that doctrine 2 return me one correct row (the first in db with id 3), but other row with id 3 are same as the first correct row. This makes only if two or more records in table **UsersList** and column **user_id** are same. Sorry for my english, but I hope that you understand me :)

Comment: Maybe try with ```findById($user->getId());```

Comment: It's same, because I specified that reference column is id.

Comment: Shouldn't ```UserList::id``` -> ```User``` be a ManyToOne relation instead of a oneToOne ? That might be that :)

Comment: It could be, but I remove all reference annotations and tried to get all records from table UsersList (`findAll()` function), but I have same problem. Sql query was: `SELECT t0.user_id AS user_id1, t0.parent_id AS parent_id2 
FROM users_list t0`. It could be doctrine bug?

Comment: I tried notORM and everything works fine. So the problem is in Doctrine.

Comment: Cool, i've updated my answer. Is the part about findOneBy instead of findOne valid ?

Comment: I changed `findById($user->getId())` to `findById($user)` and remove the second sentence, becouse `find()` or `findOne()` always return object. All other is OK.